# If $ \lim_{n \to \infty} (2 x_{n + 1} - x_{n}) = x $, then is it true that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = x $?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is a sequence in $ \mathbb{R} $ and $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (2 x_{n + 1} - x_{n}) = x $, then is it necessarily true that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = x?
$$

Could anyone kindly offer suggestions on how to approach this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120867/limit-of-sequence-x-nn/122716#122716. Look at the Lemma, which applies to $y_n = e^{x_n}$.

Comment: As @BerrickCalebFillmore proof is difficult to describe, I encourage to see also my proof below. (Normally I do not write it, but here are many long answers that contain more complicated proofs.)

Comment: Nice answer by Martin R for [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823080/with-y-n-a-sequence-of-real-numbers-prove-that-if-y-n-x-n-12x-n-conver).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $ \epsilon > 0 $. Then there exists an $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ sufficiently large so that
$$
\forall k \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
x - \epsilon < 2 x_{N + k} - x_{N + k - 1} < x + \epsilon.
$$
This means that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ccccc}
   x - \epsilon  & < &  2 x_{N + 1} -   x_{N}     & < &    x + \epsilon, \\
2 (x - \epsilon) & < &  4 x_{N + 2} - 2 x_{N + 1} & < & 2 (x + \epsilon), \\
4 (x - \epsilon) & < &  8 x_{N + 3} - 4 x_{N + 2} & < & 4 (x + \epsilon), \\
8 (x - \epsilon) & < & 16 x_{N + 4} - 8 x_{N + 3} & < & 8 (x + \epsilon), \\
\vdots           &   & \vdots                     &   & \vdots
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
Summing the first $ m $ lines of this system of inequalities yields
$$
(2^{m} - 1) (x - \epsilon) < 2^{m} x_{N + m} - x_{N} < (2^{m} - 1) (x + \epsilon).
$$
Dividing this throughout by $ 2^{m} $, we obtain
$$
  \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{m}} \right) (x - \epsilon)
< x_{N + m} - \frac{x_{N}}{2^{m}}
< \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{m}} \right) (x + \epsilon).
$$
Letting $ m \to \infty $, we then get
$$
x - \epsilon \leq \liminf_{m \to \infty} x_{N + m} = \liminf_{n \to \infty} x_{n}
\quad \text{and} \quad
\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = \limsup_{m \to \infty} x_{N + m} \leq x + \epsilon.
$$
However, $ \epsilon $ is arbitrary, so
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = x,
$$
which implies that $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = x $.

Answer (score 4):

Define $y_n=x_n-x$. You will find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(2y_{n+1}-y_n)=0$

**Response to Andre's comment**

@AndreNicolas
I agree the above line is not a rigorous proof. So here is the whole proof.

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(2y_{n+1}-y_n)=0$, so
$\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists N$ s.t. $\forall n>N, |2y_{n+1}-y_n|<\epsilon$

Define $A=|y_N|$, so, $|y_{N+1}|<(A+\epsilon)/2$

Then, it is not hard to prove through mathematical induction that

$$
\forall \text{positive integer} k,  |y_{N+k}|<\frac{A}{2^k}+\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\epsilon}{2^i}< \frac{A}{2^k} + \epsilon
$$

Now define $M=\lceil \log_2(A/\epsilon)\rceil$, then $\forall n>N+M, |y_n|<2\epsilon$

Thus $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_n=0. \quad \blacksquare $

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it has to be true.
Take $(a_n), (b_n)$, such that $a_n = 2^n \cdot x_n$ and $b_n = 2^n$. Now calculate:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{b_{n+1} - b_{n}} =
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1} x_{n+1} - 2^n x_n}{2^{n+1} -2^n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}2 x_{n+1} - x_n = x
$$

Notice $x_n = \frac{a_n}{b_n} \wedge b_n \to \infty^+$. Above limit exists, so [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) ends the proof.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{b_{n+1} - b_{n}} = x$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: I didn’t expect my proof to be called ‘complicated’, as I was proving it from first principles. I originally intended to directly apply the Stolz-Cesàro Theorem, but I decided instead to derive an instance of it in order to solve the OP’s problem. Hence, if you were to derive the Stolz-Cesàro Theorem in your solution, it would turn out to be essentially the same as mine, and so the reduction in complexity is merely cosmetic. Anyway, I have given you a +1 for your nice effort.

Comment: A great idea!  This should be the "canonical" answer.

Answer (score 2):

The assertion is true even in the more general setting of a locally convex topological vector space (l.c.t.v.s.).

---

> **Theorem:** Let $ X $ be an l.c.t.v.s. with base field $ \mathbb{F} $ ($ = \mathbb{R} $ or $ \mathbb{C} $). Let $ x \in X $ and suppose that $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is a sequence in $ X $ satisfying $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (2 x_{n + 1} - x_{n}) = x $. Then $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = x $.

*Proof*

Suppose that the topology of $ X $ is generated by the family $ (p_{i})_{i \in I} $ of semi-norms. Define a new sequence $ (y_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ in $ X $ by
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
y_{n} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} x_{n} - x.
$$
As
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
2 x_{n + 1} - x_{n} - x = 2 y_{n + 1} - y_{n},
$$
we obtain $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (2 y_{n + 1} - y_{n}) = 0_{X} $. Now, fix an arbitrary $ i \in I $ and an arbitrary $ \epsilon > 0 $. Then there exists an $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ sufficiently large so that
$$
\forall k \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
{p_{i}}(2 y_{N + k} - y_{N + k - 1}) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
In particular,
$$
\forall k \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
  {p_{i}}(2^{k} y_{N + k} - 2^{k - 1} y_{N + k - 1})
< 2^{k - 1} \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2}. \quad (\spadesuit)
$$
It follows readily that
\begin{align*}
\forall m \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
       {p_{i}}(2^{m} y_{N + m} - y_{N})
& =    {p_{i}} \left( \sum_{k = 1}^{m} (2^{k} y_{N + k} - 2^{k - 1} y_{N + k - 1}) \right)
       \quad (\text{Telescoping sum.}) \\
& \leq \sum_{k = 1}^{m} {p_{i}}(2^{k} y_{N + k} - 2^{k - 1} y_{N + k - 1}) \quad
       (\text{Triangle Inequality.}) \\
& <    \sum_{k = 1}^{m} 2^{k - 1} \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2} \quad
       (\text{By $ \spadesuit $.}) \\
& =    (2^{m} - 1) \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
  {p_{i}} \left( y_{N + m} - \frac{1}{2^{m}} y_{N} \right)
< \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{m}} \right) \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
By another application of the Triangle Inequality,
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
     {p_{i}}(y_{N + m}) - {p_{i}} \left( \frac{1}{2^{m}} y_{N} \right)
\leq {p_{i}} \left( y_{N + m} - \frac{1}{2^{m}} y_{N} \right).
$$
This implies that
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
  {p_{i}}(y_{N + m})
< {p_{i}} \left( \frac{1}{2^{m}} y_{N} \right) +
  \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{m}} \right) \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
Next, pick an $ m \in \mathbb{N} $ large enough so that $ {p_{i}} \left( \dfrac{1}{2^{n}} y_{N} \right) < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq m} $. Hence,
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq m}: \quad
{p_{i}}(y_{N + n}) < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq N + m}: \quad
{p_{i}}(y_{n}) < \epsilon.
$$
As $ \epsilon $ is arbitrary, we see that $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} {p_{i}}(y_{n}) = 0 $. Finally, as $ i \in I $ is arbitrary, we conclude that $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} y_{n} = 0_{X} $, thus yielding $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = x $. $ \quad \blacksquare $

---

> **Question:** Is the theorem true if $ X $ is just a general topological vector space? In other words, if $ X $ is *not* locally convex, then does the conclusion of the theorem still hold?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lim$ $(2x_{n+1}-x_n)=x.$ Then for every $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that when $n\geq N,$ $|(2x_{n+1}-x_n)-x|<\epsilon.$

Fix $\epsilon>0.$ Then
$$|x_n-x|=|x_n+(x_n-x_n)-x|=|(2x_n-x_n)-x|<\epsilon.$$

...Although I'm not exactly sure about that last step. My issue is that this is a recursive sequence. So intuitively, as $n\to\infty,$ we get that $x_{n+1}=x_n.$ I'm not exactly sure how to deal with this one facet rigorously.

Comment: see my edited answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The beautiful idea of @Tacet: -- maybe we can generalize it?  Say we have two sequences $(x_n)$, and a sequence of  numbers $(c_n)$ $>0$ such that
$$(c_n+1) x_{n+1}- c_n x_n$$
has limit $x$.  Write this as

$$\frac{a_{n+1} x_{n+1} - a_n x_n}{a_{n+1} - a_n} \to x$$
where
$c_{n} + 1 = \frac{a_{n+1} }{a_{n+1} - a_n}$ and [so](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Solve%5C%2891%29%20c%2B1%20%3D%3D%20Divide%5B%CE%B1%2C%5C%2840%29%CE%B1-1%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2844%29%20%CE%B1%5C%2893%29)
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1+ \frac{1}{c_n}$$
With $a_1=1$ we get
$$a_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1+ \frac{1}{c_k})$$

In order to apply Cesaro-Stolz,  we want $a_n \to \infty$ and this is [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) to $\sum \frac{1}{c_n} \to \infty$.

( works if $(c_n)$ constant, or bounded above, or bounded above by an arithmetic progression)

Note: the idea of Cesaro-Stolz is the following : we can strengthen a given drink past $p$ proof by adding a sufficient amount of drinks of strenght $\ge p$.