# Prove that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is absolutely convergent and $\lim b_n=0$, then $\lim (a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+...+a_nb_0)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've been stuck in this one for a while. Could anyone help by giving some hints on how to approach this problem?

> Prove that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is absolutely convergent and $\lim  b_n=0$, then $\lim (a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+...+a_nb_0)=0$.

Comment: use the fact that the tail of the series, i.e. $\sum_{k=n}^\infty |a_k| $ converges to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, and that the sequence $b_n$ is bounded. This allows you to  split the desired sequence into two regimes, where in one you rely on convergence of $b_n$, and in the other one on convergence of the tail.

Comment: @Hayk Please consider making it an answer.

Comment: @GNUSupporter, thanks; I've expanded on the comment to make it an answer.

Comment: Slightly more general: [$A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $b_n \to B$ implies $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k} \to AB$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1823486/42969).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix any $\varepsilon >0$ small, and let $k\in \mathbb{N}$ be so that 
$$
\sum_{i=k}^\infty |a_i| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2M} ,
$$
where $M>0$ is fixed as an upper bound for $|b_n|$, i.e. we have  $|b_n| \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ($b_n$ is bounded due to the fact that it converges). 
Let also $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be so large that $|b_{i-k}| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2 \sum_{i=0}^k |a_i|}$, for all $i=n, n+1,...$ .

We then get
$$
|a_0b_n +...+a_n b_0| \leq |a_0 b_n +...+a_k b_{n-k}| + |a_{k+1} b_{n-k-1}+...+a_n b_0| \leq \\
\sum_{i=0}^k |a_i| \frac{\varepsilon}{2 \sum_{i=0}^k |a_i|} + M \frac{\varepsilon}{2M} \leq \\
\frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.
$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we are done.