Let $x_{n+1}^2=x_n+\frac{1}{n+1}$, $x_{n+1}>0, x_1=1$. How to prove that $x_n\to 1$?

Let $x_{n+1}^2=x_n+\frac{1}{n+1}$, $x_{n+1}>0, x_1=1$. How to prove that $x_n\to 1$?

$x_{n+1}<x_n+\frac{1}{n+1}$ seems not enough!
Any ideas? Compuationally, $n$ large $x_n$ decresing. How to prove mathematically?

You can prove that $x_n$ is eventually decreasing by induction once you find $n_0$ such that $x_{n_0+1}\le x_{n_0}.$ Try $n_0=2.$

Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120867/42969

To prove $x_n \to 1$, use the following steps:
Mathematical Induction

Base case: $x_1 = 1$ (given).
Inductive step: Assume $x_k = 1$ for some $k$. Prove $x_{k+1} = 1$.

Sequence Definition
Given $x_{2n+1} = x_n \cdot x_{n+1}$, we can rewrite it as:
Recurrence Relation
$x_{2n+1} = x_n \cdot x_{n+1}$
Convergence Proof

Since $x_{n+1} > 0$, the sequence is positive.
Show the sequence is bounded: $1 \leq x_n$ for all $n$.
Use the recurrence relation to prove $x_{2n} \leq x_{2n+1}$.
Apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Limit Proof

Let $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$.
From the recurrence relation: $L = L^2$.
Solve for $L$: $L = 1$.

Detailed Solution
For a more detailed solution, consider the following:

$x_1 = 1$.
$x_3 = x_1 \cdot x_2 = 1 \cdot x_2$.
$x_5 = x_2 \cdot x_3 = x_2 \cdot (1 \cdot x_2) = x_2^2$.
$x_{2n+1} = x_n \cdot x_{n+1} = x_{n-1}^{2^{n-1}} \cdot x_n^{2^{n-1}}$.

This pattern suggests $x_n$ converges to 1.
