# Simple demonstration for $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}) = \frac{1}{e}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the simple demonstration with elementary means for Lalescu Sequence:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}) = \frac{1}{e}?$$

(Traian Lalescu-romanian mathematician (1882-1929))

Comment: Stirling approximation is a good way.

Comment: For your curiosity, it is possible to show that, for large values of $n$, $\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}\simeq \frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{2 e n}$

Answer (score 1):

Apply [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) to $a_n=(n!)^{1/n}$ and $b_n=n$, then the desired limit equals
$$
\ell=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}
$$
Now recall [one more formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142348/is-there-a-standard-way-to-compute-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracnnn1)
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|c_n|^{1/n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right|
$$
Taking $c_n=n!/n^n$ we get
$$
\ell
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\frac{n^n}{n!}
=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}=\frac{1}{e}
$$

Comment: The way you use a reciprocal Stolz-Cesaro lemma, which should be demonstrated first!